# Is excited electrons life-time = half-life?

Tags: atomic-physics

Everywhere I read something related to excited electrons in atoms I only see the word "lifetime".

For example most excited states have a lifetime of a few nano to micro seconds and metastable states have a lifetime of a few miliseconds as far as I understand.

Shouldn't we say "half-life" instead? Since we are dealing with probabilities..

I'm surprised because I don't see the word "half-life" anywhere when talking about excited states. Therefore I would love to set the record straight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Half-life ($t_{1/2}$) and lifetime ($\tau$) are related to one another.

$$
t_{1/2} = \tau \ln(2)
$$

From the equivalent equations,

$$
N(t) = N_0 \left(\frac {1}{2}\right)^{\frac{t}{t_{1/2}}} \\
  N(t) = N_0 e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}
$$

It’s just convention; forms adopted by different fields. I would say the half life approach is more intuitively understandable, so I can see this being used in fields such a radioactivity where safety is a concern.

However, is optics, rate equations are a hugely important tool, and using lifetimes makes the mathematics slightly easier to understand and work with.

Source https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-life